# glossary/dictionary corpus for NLP task

Tags: corpora, resource-request, dictionary

I am looking for glossary/dictionary corpus in machine readable form. Basically huge file/db which would contain word and its definition. Here is sample:

```
Authenticity: a feature that characterizes naturally occurring corpus data
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two resources are particularly popular.

1. [WordNet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/)
2. [Wiktionary](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/backup-index.html)

Comment: Thank you, WordNet is more of thesaurus and Wiktionary definition are a bit too long. I can try to cut Wiktionary definition, but wonder if there something readily available.

Comment: @user1700890 WordNet has definitions and examples too, though not for all words. Try out a few words.

Answer (score 1):

The [Macmillan Dictionary has an API](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/tools/aboutapi.html) that you can use.